# <job-tracker> and <name-node> in oozie pig configuraction action - where can i find them?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I'm trying to run my first oozie workflow, simple `<pig>` action .
Can anyone help with these two tags:

```
    <job-tracker>[JOB-TRACKER]</job-tracker>
    <name-node>[NAME-NODE]</name-node>
```

As I understand, paramaters refer to existing configuration.
I'm using preconfigurered environment so can you please help where to find these values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have access to see Hadoop's conf files, open core-site.xml to find the name node from the below property.

```
 <property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://ec2-1-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000</value>
 </property>
```

Open mapred-site.xml to find the job tracker.

```
<property>
   <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
   <value>ec2-1-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:54311</value>
</property>
```

Then your values will be.

```
nameNode=hdfs://ec2-1-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000
jobTracker=ec2-1-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:54311
```

Comment: what is namenode in job.properties file?